# Woocommerece Single product page warning

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have this error on a single product page after updating woocommerce 2.x to 3.x. 
[Here is the link](https://himalayangem.com/product/sku084-amazing-pure-red-un-treated-ruby-0-98-carats/)

> deprecated since version 3.0! Use WC_Product::get_gallery_image_ids instead. in /www/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3839 class="post-16784 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail product_cat-rough product_cat-spinel qode-product-with-gallery first instock shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple">

Can anyone help me?

Comment: First thing - this is a warning due to API deprecation (so maybe disabling such warning is an option?). You should look into the code especially on `/www/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3839` what's up there. And the second thing please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
It's sometimes hard to answer questions when the error is only thing you have. We would really like to help :) but sometimes it's too little info on the specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

That can only get correctly fixed by updating your theme/plugins. If you want to proceed with this, please make a backup before touching anything, otherwise, read below.

That's a deprecated notice only, it doesn't break anything for now, but it will if you keep updating WooCommerce and not theme/plugins, but that's gonna be a couple of years from now since Wordpress (incl. WooCommerce, which was bought by Automattic, the company behind Wordpress) is famous for not breaking backwards compatibility.

Temporary fix if you don't want to update your theme/plugins is to open your `wp-config.php` file and look for `WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY`, if you find it, set it to `false`, otherwise add `define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);` to the file. This will fix it for now.

Comment: How can I change the file's permission? Because after adding this piece of code `define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);` to **wp-config** file I can't save that.

Comment: You need to have FTP access or Apache (the web server) need to have permission to write. Ask your system administrator.